# Delay in a jquery function using the .show() and .hide() functions

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a fairly simple gallery preview style program, shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#moving_photos').mouseover(function() {
    $('#img4').delay(1000).hide(500);
    $('#img3').delay(2000).hide(500);
    $('#img2').delay(3000).hide(500);
    $('#img2').delay(5000).show(500);
    $('#img3').delay(6000).show(500);
    $('#img4').delay(7000).show(500);
});
```

});

My issue comes up after the first three images have been hidden. There is a roughly five second delay before the next image shows again, and it looks more like the function resetting than completion of the function. Any help you can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: can you give HTML too

Comment: What do you mean by "looks more like the function resetting"? Also, there is a 5 second delay because your function calls are not asynchronous. You should instead use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delay()` does not work with `hide()` and `show()`. It does work with `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`

```
 $('#moving_photos').mouseover(function() {
    $('#img4').delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
    $('#img3').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
    $('#img2').delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
    $('#img2').delay(5000).fadeIn(500);
    $('#img3').delay(6000).fadeIn(500);
    $('#img4').delay(7000).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Also, if you want the images to fadeIn quicker...

change the delay time. 1000 equals 1 second.

So there is a 7 second delay for your #img4 before it starts to fadeIn

Comment: Didn't realize that it wasn't compatible with those functions. You were right, after spending a few minutes playing with the times, it worked perfectly. Thanks man